# React Router V5 best way to use context variable in route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In My app I have my routes defined, as per below:

```
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Header />
          <div className="App">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Redirect to="/home" />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path={["/home", "/"]} component={Home} />
              <Route path="/account/:id" render={(props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => <Account {...props} />} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

What I want to know is, this can be tricky, If I wanted my route to have a prefix from my context i.e variable how would I do this, but the twist is the variable comes from an api response?

so what if i wanted the route `/contextVariable/home` but `contextVariable` is from an api response and is stored in a context value, I know how I would bring that variable into the component but how would the routes handle it i.e from not being `/undefined/home` as in the response would need to finish before being inserted into the route?

Any idea's?

Comment: Would basePath work, when the baseName would change according to the context variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had once made a project that had similar requirement. In that, instead of declaring dynamic routes, I fetched a routes array from the state which was an object array with component, path, and few other parameters. By default I added the initial landing page and not found page:

```
const [routes, setRoutes] = React.useState([
{
 component: HomeComponent,
 path: '/',
},
{
 component: NoMatchPage,
 path: '*',
}
])
```

And then I had the request in a useEffect block which would update this state like so:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
 // call api()
 const oldRoutes = routes;
 const noMatchPage = oldRoutes.pop();
 const newRoutes = [...oldRoutes, 
    responseFromApi.map(
     routeItem => 
        ({
          component: ComponentName, 
          path: routeItem.path
        })
     ), noMatchPage]
 setRoutes(newRoutes)
},[])
```

### Edit 1 : Cause I'm forgetful

Sorry, I forgot the main part, here's how the Route rendering would be:

```
<Switch>
    {
      routes.map(routeItem =>
        <Route path={routeItem.path} component={routeItem.component} />
      )
    }
</Switch>
```

Also if you want to avoid the extra code in useEffect, you could simply do this:

```
React.useEffect(()=>{
 // call api()
 setRoutes(responseFromApi.map(
     routeItem => 
        ({
          component: ComponentName, 
          path: routeItem.path
        })
     ))
},[])
```

and then

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path={["/home", "/"]} component={Home} />
    {
      routes.map(routeItem =>
        <Route path={routeItem.path} component={routeItem.component} />
      )
    }
    <Route component={NotFound} />
</Switch>
```

### Edit 2 : Cause I'm ignorant

In the case where the user enters the URL directly and `Switch` is unable to identify the `Route` and therefore loads the `NotFoundPage`, you could do the following:

1. Set a condition when you start loading your paths, inside your `useEffect` block:

```
const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(false);
React.useEffect(() =>
    {
      setLoading(true);
      // load paths
      setLoading(false);
    }, [])
```

2. While the fetch is in progress, show a `Loader` to the user:

```
return
    (
    <>
        {
           loading ? 
             <LoaderComponent /> : 
             <Switch>
                // same as before
             </Switch>
        }
    </>
    )
```

Preferable show something for the user to read, so they don't get irritated, cause patience is a thing of the past. Hope this helps!

Comment: So what did your route component look like? as in how are the routes defined

Comment: Thanks for this, but if the basepath is from an api, and the app loads first time, what would be the way to make sure the routing component does not get the basePath before the api has finished fetching the response, if it does try and get the basename before the response has finished then it will add 'undefined' in the basename and the route will show the not found component?

Comment: I'm sorry, that completely slipped my mind.  
What you could do in this case is put a condition before the `Switch` block which will check if your path fetch API is loading, if loading show the user some `Loader`, else load the routes. Let me put it in the answer

Comment: Or a simpler way do you think is to add an undefined route redirect? i.e `<Route exact path={["/undefined/home"]}><Redirect to={`/${basePrefix}/home`} /></Route>`

Comment: I wouldn't suggest that, as it would still result in the same outcome if `basePrefix` is received from the fetch route API's response. The flow would be: User enters URL with `basePrefix` - `domain/subPath/home` > The project tries to match the path > None found, therefore `NoFoundComponent` loads

Comment: Ok, but if you have an array for the routes, you currently just have path and component, in my case I have the render props also? So I presume I would just add that in ass a property for the object?

Another way I was thinking was to make use of the status object from react-query as I am fetching using that, as per your example above, I could add a success flag into the routing component so it would only render on success of the api, which would get rid of the undefined problem also.

Comment: That is the right way to do it. Only after receiving the success status, you should proceed. My bad. And yes, you should store any and all additional `props` to be used in your object array, and pass it into the component like: `<Route path={'path'} render={ rItem => <Component {...props} />` where props will be received from the map function's iterated object. Now the issue is importing the desired Components that have been rendered, for that you'd either have to import by default or you could use dynamic importing. Also, please accept my answer if it helps, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this with a React Context then this is the pattern I'd suggest. Create a React Context that holds the API logic to fetch a "base path" and expose that out to consumers. Consumers will take the provided "base path" value and prepend it to all link targets and route paths.

Example:

BasePathProvider

```
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

const BasePath = createContext({
  basepath: ""
});

const BasePathProvider = ({ children }) => {
  ... logic to fetch basepath ...

  return (
    <BasePath.Provider value={{ basepath }}>
      {children}
    </BasePath.Provider>
  );
};

const useBasePath = () => useContext(BasePath);
```

Header

```
const Header = () => {
  const { basepath } = useBasePath();

  return (
    ...
    <Link to={`${basepath}/`}>Home</Link>
    <Link to={`${basepath}/account/${/* some id value */}`}>
      Account
    </Link>
    ...
  );
};
```

App

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header />
      <BasePath.Consumer>
        {({ basepath }) => (
          <Switch>
            <Redirect from={`${basepath}/`} exact to={`${basepath}/home`} />
            <Route path={`${basepath}/home`} component={Home} />
            <Route path={`${basepath}/account/:id`} component={Account} />
            <Route component={NotFound} />
          </Switch>
        )}
      </BasePath.Consumer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import BasePathProvider from "../path/to/BasePathProvider";

...

<Router>
  <BasePathProvider>
    <App />
  </BasePathProvider>
</Router>
```

[image: Edit react-router-v5-best-way-to-use-context-variable-in-route]

**Note:** You might also want/need to implement a "loading" state to conditionally render the `BasePathProvider` component's `children` until the `basepath` value has been fetched.

Comment: Thanks for this, but if the basepath is from an api, and the app loads first time, what would be the way to make sure the routing component does not get the basePath before the api has finished fetching the response, if it does try and get the basename before the response has finished then it will add 'undefined' in the basename and the route will show the not found component?

Comment: @Sole You can use a loading state while the initial API request is made and conditionally render a loading indicator until the basepath resolves and switch over to your router/routes.